# Exponential distribution - Calculate the probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be exponential distributed with parameter $\lambda>0$, i.e. it holds that $P[X\leq x]=1-e^{-\lambda x}$.

Calculate $P[X\cdot E[X]\geq 1]$.

$$$$

It holds that $E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, right?

So we get \begin{align*}P[X\cdot E[X]\geq 1]&=P\left [X\cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}\geq 1\right ]=P\left [X\geq \lambda \right ]\\ & =1-P[X<\lambda ]=1-P[X\leq\lambda ]+P[X=\lambda ] \\ & =1-\left (1-e^{-\lambda \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}}\right )+\frac{\lambda^{\lambda}}{e^{-\lambda}}\cdot \lambda!\\ & =e^{-1}+\frac{\lambda^{\lambda}}{e^{-\lambda}}\cdot \lambda!\end{align*}
Is that correct?

Comment: You have a misstep on your second line. The probability of $X = \lambda$ is a pretty negligible, zero-like number. So actually the second line is correct as it stands, it's the third where you misinterpret the latter probability.

Comment: The exponential distribution is a continuous random variable. So individual points carry zero probability: $P(X = \lambda) = 0$. You may have confused the exponential distribution with the Poisson there.

Comment: Ahh ok! Thank  you very much!! :-)

Comment: So the result is $e^{-1}$, right? @0XLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that $E[X]= \frac{1}{\lambda}$. But the equation
$$P[X\geq \lambda] = 1-P[X \leq\lambda] + P[X=\lambda]$$
is not correct since for a continuos distribution the term $P[X=\lambda]$ is not really defined (as A rural reader pointed out). Because of the definition of the distribution function with the help of an integral, namely
$$P[X \leq x] := \int_{0}^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt$$
for $x \geq 0$ and $P[X \leq x] = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ one can see that
$$P[X \geq \lambda] = 1- \int_0^{\lambda} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt = 1- (1-e^{-\lambda^2}) = e^{-\lambda^2}$$

Comment: Technically, $P(X \geq \lambda) = 1 - P(X \leq \lambda) + P(X = \lambda)$ is correct and $P(X = \lambda)$ is defined. It is just that $P(X = \lambda) = 0$.

Comment: Of course you are right - I should have been clearer about that.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)